# Como transformar inteiros em byte na linguagem Python?

Tags: python, int, byte

Estou usando o módulo pyserial para enviar dados seriais, então tenho uma lista de valores como:

```
Valores = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

Preciso transformar os valores da lista em bytes para poder enviar, pois se eu tento enviar assim:

```
Serial.write(Valores)
```

Ou assim:

```
Serial.write(10)
```

Recebo esse erro:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 61, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Mas se enviar conforme a linha abaixo funciona!

```
Serial.write(b'10')
```

Como posso fazer essa conversão dos valores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Python 3 o próprio built-in "bytes" faz isso:

```
>>> bytes([40,10,20,30])
b'(\n\x14\x1e'
```

Em Python 2, o que hoje são os "bytes" era o equivalente as strings. No entanto no Python 3 separaram: strings são objetos contendo texto, em que cada elemento é um codepoint de unicode - e não interessa seu valor numérico, e a antiga "byte-string" ficou sendo conhecida como bytes, e funcionando como em C: se por acaso um valor tem uma representação ASCII (valor numérico de 32 até 128), ele é impresso, senão é impresso com a codificação de dois dígitos hexadecimal. Internamente, é apenas uma sequência numérica de bytes, e já é o tipo aceito por todas as  funções relevantes que lidam com a porta serial.

No caso dos seus exemplos especificamente, você pode fazer:

```
serial.write(bytes((10,))
```

(o `(10,)` é uma tupla de um único número - a vírgula final não é opcional.

Ou:

serial.write(b"\x0a")

O prefixo "b" para as aspas indica que é um literal de bytes, não de texto -  e você pode colocar números diretamente na notação hexadecimal dentro das aspas.

COmo vocẽ está usando comunicação serial, é possível que tenha que enviar registros de dados com vários campos com tamanho pré-determinado. Nesse caso, você pode usar o módulo "struct" que acompanha o Python: ele transforma num objeto bytes, na ordem correta, uma sequência de parâmetros de acordo com uma string de formatação - https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Por exemplo, se você tiver que mandar dois números de 16 bits sem sinal, seguido de um número em ponto flutuante de 32bit:

```
>>> struct.pack("<HHf", 40000, 50000, 3.28)
b'@\x9cP\xc3\x85\xebQ@'
```

Para extrair os números de um objeto do tipo bytes, basta utiliza-lo como uma sequência normal. Em Python 3 um elemento de uma sequência de bytes é um número de 8 bits sem sinal:

```
>>> a = b"minha_resposta:\xff"
>>> print(list(a))
[109, 105, 110, 104, 97, 95, 114, 101, 115, 112, 111, 115, 116, 97, 58, 255]
```

Em Python 2 é necessário a conversão explícita do elemento de bytes para inteiro - e pode ser usada a função `ord` para isso:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Jan 17 2018, 14:28:32) 
>>> a = b"minha_resposta:\xff"
>>> print(list(a))
['m', 'i', 'n', 'h', 'a', '_', 'r', 'e', 's', 'p', 'o', 's', 't', 'a', ':', '\xff']
>>> print(map(ord, a))
[109, 105, 110, 104, 97, 95, 114, 101, 115, 112, 111, 115, 116, 97, 58, 255]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela excelente resposta! Funcionou!

Comment: Você pode explicar como fazer o caminho inverso? Receber os bytes e transformar em inteiros.

Answer (score 6):

Pode fazer:

```
print((65).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
```

[Documentação do `to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

Se a preferência for fazer com uma lista use assim:

```
bytes([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
```

[Documentação de `bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/J35UEF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dcvtvqdu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertIntToByte.py).

Comment: só énecessario se for codificar números que usam mais de 1 byte . Mas no caso caso, de comunicação com a serial, vai ser melhor usar o  `struct` por que a chance é dos números serem campos preenchisdos dentro vários outros.

Comment: @jsbueno sim, eu estava complementando com as duas opções